# Grey Screen on CT Settings > Payments after upgrade to 2.5

Tags: cartthrob

I've upgraded to EE2.7.3 and CT 2.5 now when I go to Cartthrob > Settings > Payments I'm getting a grey screen and all navigation is disabled (have to click back button to get out). Is anyone else experiencing this or know of a fix. Display Output Profiler and Template Debug not outputting anything either.

Comment: I wonder if it's due to a memory issue? One simple thing to try would be to delete all payment methods from the payments folder that you're not using at present. Another possibility is that you have files in there that are not payment gateway files (sometimes people make backups like ZIPs or something like :Cartthrob_eway.php_backup that could cause CT to choke on reading those files)

Comment: Thanks for that Chris. I'm going to try a fresh upgrade first and then I'll try clearing out some of the payment methods. I'll report back after I've tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall seemed to fix problem with greyscreen. First try must have corrupted/dropped some files.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with *CartThrob 2.7.1* on *EE 2.11.2* - the **Modules : Payments** setting page wasn't loading past the EE header and displaying a **memory error** at the foot of the source HTML.

The solution involved removing **all** gateway php files in */system/expressionengine/third_party/cartthrob/payment_gateways/* **except** *Cartthrob_payment_gateway.php* and the gateway(s) you require - e.g. *Cartthrob_paypal_express.php*